# ¿Cómo comunicarse entre un WebView y la ChromeTab?

Tags: javascript, php, android, webview-android

Tengo una app que es un webview y acaba llevando a una ChromeTab.
Por lo que he leído es imposible pasarle una cookie o mantener la sesion.

Buscando soluciones.

1. Ideal: Leer un fichero local.
   ¿Es posible leer ficheros locales con javaScript pero utilizando paths (sin inputs, es decir, sin interacción del usuario)?
2. Tal vez podría obtener el sid en el webview con php, pasarlo por GET al ChromeTab y desde allí cargarlo. (Me falta comprobar si es funcional)

Comment: ¿cuáles son los datos que te interesa mantener?

Comment: el sitio web con el que trabajas es tuyo? es decir, lo puedes modificar?

Comment: Que la sesión de login se mantenga iniciada y por otro lado un json grande que sería como una mini base de datos.